# python class reserved methods

Tags: python, class

i'm writing a python class that create connection to remote server by using fabric2 library.

I'm wondering which is the right writing design for my class.

for example:

```py
class SshToServer:
    """ssh connection to server."""

    def __init__(self, ip, user, ssh_key_path):
        self.ssh_client = Connection(
            host=ip,
            user=user,
            port=22,
            connect_kwargs={"key_filename": ssh_key_path},
            inline_ssh_env=True,
        )

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.ssh_client.close()
```

First it would be great to get general info before:

1. I should use __enter__ and __exit__ methods only if i plan to create the object with **"with"** statement? there is a situation that i will choose to use those methods without the **"with"** statement creation?
2. What is the meaning of using both __init__ and __enter__ inside the class? what's the difference between them? because they both run when i create object. using one of them is enough ?
   Same for using __exit__ and __del__ class methods.

**back to my code:**

now i'm going to write my module and basically i want to create the connection object based on some parameter, for example base on environment.

if it's environment X connect to server X - same for environment Y:

```
with SshToServer(ip=BLA_1, user=BLA_1, ssh_key_path=BLA_1) as conn:
    do_stuff...
with SshToServer(ip=BLA_2, user=BLA+2, ssh_key_path=BLA_2) as conn:
    do_stuff...
```

and it's the same methods in both connection, it's just different remote server.

so i'm guessing that using **"with"** is not the smart way in that case (cause i duplicate the code).

i want to change the object creation way to:

`conn = SshToServer(...)
do_stuff...
conn.__exit__ / conn.__del__`

But i'm confusing between those 4 methods and when i should use them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, they are only intended for usage with `with`.
2. In your sample code, `__init__` is called first to create (actually only initialize) an object (as usual), then `__enter__` is called to use the object as context manager (only in `with)`. Both methods have their own uses.

Calling special methods directly is usually a bad idea. Exception: Calling in a special method the same method of the super class.

Main advantage of `with` is that `__exit__` is called under nearly all circumstances and can't be forgotten.

In your code you could e.g. write the two `with` as one like

```
conn = SshToServer(...)  # Somehow select which object to create
with conn:
    do_stuff...
```

This is much cleaner and safer than calling special methods directly.

Answer (score 0):

`__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are use to perform setup and teardown actions.
It will automatically close the connection for you. `__exit__` is called when you exit the `with` scope.

In this case you are creating two new connections so you need to create two context managers.

I don't know about the Connection class. if it lets you configure user separately then you can do is

```
with SshToServer(ip=BLA_1, ssh_key_path=BLA_1) as conn:
    conn.user = BLA_1
    // do some stuff
   conn.user = BLA_2
   // do some stuff
```